# Magento 2 : Add new Product attribute options

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, attribute-options

I have added a product attribute programmatically. 
so in store->product->attribute it shows option values readonly.
Is it possible to add new option from admin side ?

Ex.[image]

because it is system generated attribute ('user_defined' => false) it doesn't show 'Add' button.

so how can I add more option or new option. (not programmatically) 
Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: You can update "user_defined" to true from the database directly. You can get "attribute_id" from `eav_attributes` table and then find that "attribute_id" in `catalog_eav_attributes` and update "user_defined" column value to true.